# Android BluetoothGatt writeCharacteristic with response

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

From the documentations I see how to write without response like this:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = ...
characteristic.setValue(bytes);
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

How do you preform a write request operation WITH response?

(In iOS there is option to select write type CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse and CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse)

Comment: Hi david, did you get the response from mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic), if yes please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> public void setWriteType (int writeType)
>
> Added in API level 18 Set the write type for this characteristic
>
> Setting the write type of a characteristic determines how the
>   writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) function write this
>   characteristic.
>
> Parameters writeType  The write type to for this characteristic. Can be
>   one of: WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT, WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE or
>   WRITE_TYPE_SIGNED.

Answer (score 7):

1. Your characteristic should be writable.

Checking whether the characteristic is writable:

```
(characteristic.getProperties() & (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE))) != 0
```

2. [BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#writeCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic)) returns boolean flag indicating whether writing succeeded (true if so).
3. Once the BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic succeeds [BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicWrite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) callback is executed with the characteristic with the value that you specified.

Comment: I am doing all this and getting successful response for both write and onCharacteristicWrite, but the peripheral is not performing the request that was sent.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I didn't mention about it. However, please note that applying different write types works under the condition that the characteristic you write the value to must be writable which is the bluetooth device-specific logic. Find out first of what type your characteristic is because it may have the same type that you demand. Once it meets the condition of being writable every WRITE_TYPE should work for you.

By analyzing BluetoothGatt's writeCharacteristic() method it is clearly visible:

```
 public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) == 0
        && (characteristic.getProperties() &
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) == 0) return false;

    if (VDBG) Log.d(TAG, "writeCharacteristic() - uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid());
    if (mService == null || mClientIf == 0 || characteristic.getValue() == null) return false;

    BluetoothGattService service = characteristic.getService();
    if (service == null) return false;

    BluetoothDevice device = service.getDevice();
    if (device == null) return false;

    synchronized(mDeviceBusy) {
        if (mDeviceBusy) return false;
        mDeviceBusy = true;
    }

    try {
        mService.writeCharacteristic(mClientIf, device.getAddress(),
            service.getType(), service.getInstanceId(),
            new ParcelUuid(service.getUuid()), characteristic.getInstanceId(),
            new ParcelUuid(characteristic.getUuid()),
            characteristic.getWriteType(), AUTHENTICATION_NONE,
            characteristic.getValue());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"",e);
        mDeviceBusy = false;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know it is my second answer but it provides elaboration to my first post. I hope you helped you somehow.